# Netty based non-blocking REST framework

Tags: java, rest, netty, nio, resteasy

I am working on a RESTfull application which requires high scalability. I am considering Netty based frameworks for RESTfull applications. I went through some of the available options and tried to get what they can offer as a non-blocking implementation. Here are my findings:

1. rest.li --> Still under experimental phase for Netty based NIO implementaions. So, not production ready.
2. RESTEasy --> Standard JBoss project which supports Netty 4.x. But,instead of full stack Netty based NIO implementation, RESTEasy is a Buffer exchange between Netty and RESTEasy. It's not taking the advantages of Netty. Therefore scalability is not as high as expected from a Netty based framework.
3. Netty-http component --> Another  option is Apache Camel integration while using Netty-http component as an endpoint for routing requests to services exposed in from of beans. I think it's same as RESTEasy, only Netty-http component uses Netty based NIO capabilities and the rest of the system would use the old IO. I don't think I would help much in gaining scalabiltiy.
4. RESTExpress --> It claims to be Netty based framework for RESTFull application. But, neither it has a decent community nor it can be trusted (Because it's very new) for enterprise application which requires high degree of security.

Before having the above findings, I wanted to use some ready to use framework and get the work done faster.

I know it's an opinion based question. But, still I seriously need help for choosing right framework for my application. If in case, there is no Netty based REST framework: would it be wise to go for plumbing low level Netty based NIO code in my application? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be surprised that BIO often times performs better than NIO particular for the case of short requests (ie no keep alive or websocket). Most REST clients and even REST in general is short requests.

Comment: Using a NIO REST framework won't make your application magically scalable. Making you application stateless and using cache headers correctly is a good start.

Comment: @eiden I am already playing with Akka-Actors with remote capabilities to make it a highly scalable and distributed application. I just wanted to just get rid of blocking nature of Servlet-API. I have started playing with Spray + Akka Actors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you really want non-blocking you need to do non-blocking from the ground up and have [proper REST clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986014/rest-based-services-in-back-end). Otherwise as stated in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758215/netty-based-non-blocking-rest-framewrok#comment29399505_19758215) the performance difference will be negligible and in many cases worse for NIO (Netty with thread sharing).

There only two libraries that I know do non-blocking from the ground up [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/) and somewhat [Finagle](http://twitter.github.io/finagle/) (its missing other things like non-blocking data access).

You should also know Tomcat and various other servlet containers that can work with JAX-RS support NIO. The issue is that even though NIO is supported it will still be a single thread per request. Only Play, Finagle, Vert.x and pure Netty (regardless of NIO) support a different shared threading model and thus have different mechanisms for doing concurrency.

Comment: I didn't get what exactly you want to say by "Proper REST client". Can you please put more light on it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I edited the answer with a link. What I mean is supporting persistent connections or using a different protocol altogether. A large impetus for Node.js and the whole non-blocking/single thread event loop is because persistent connections are becoming more common place (Websockets, Comet, etc...). Almost all traditional Java REST services will have trouble for a streaming REST API of say 10,000 long running requests regardless of NIO because of the thread/request. That being said most REST clients will do GET/POST/DELETE/PUT as a request then immediately close the connection.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the list of microframeworks I'm aware of for REST applications:

- Scalatra - http://www.scalatra.org/ (Scala + Netty)
- RestExpress - https://github.com/RestExpress/RestExpress (Java + Netty)
- Finatra - https://github.com/capotej/finatra (Scala + Finagle + Netty)

Please feel free to comment to the answer - I'll update the answer to add more.

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at [Play](http://www.playframework.com/)?

It appears that you are inclined to use Netty but if you are willing to look around a very simple [Grizzly + Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/snapshot/getting-started.html#new-from-archetype) setup will probably perform well enough.  Heck, a simple Glassfish 4.0 JAX-RS app may work well too.

Answer (score 1):

Spring 5 comes with a reactive web framework called WebFlux. You can choose from multiple servers like Netty or Undertow. A reactive non-blocking WebClient has also been added to Spring and it also has support for reactive Mongo, Redis and Cassandra (I guess more is coming soon).

Spring Boot, the 'opinionated view of Spring', will also get a new version (2.0) based on Spring 5. At the time of writing it is [expected](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestones) to be released in February.

More information on the reactive stack of Spring: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [AsyncRestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html) in Spring Framework 4.2.5.RELEASE. It can be used on top of Netty.

> Note: by default AsyncRestTemplate relies on standard JDK facilities to establish HTTP connections. You can switch to use a different HTTP library such as Apache HttpComponents, Netty, and OkHttp by using a constructor accepting an AsyncClientHttpRequestFactory.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more framework which uses Netty and RxJava, It's called [datamill](https://github.com/rchodava/datamill)

If you are interested in building web applications using a functional reactive style then should consider it.

Answer (score 0):

[Undertow 3.0](http://undertow.io/) will be on the top of [Netty (instead of XNIO)](http://undertow.io/blog/2019/04/15/Undertow-3.html). A perfect, super light, simple API to build an application like REST API server. I use it for almost any Java Microservices I have.

Comment: The [Undertow 3 repository](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/tree/3.x) hasn't seen much activity in the last 8 months.  Time to find a new horse.